# spielen-Spieler, sprechen-Sprecher but not müllen-Müller!

Tags: suffix

*-er* is one of the most productive suffixes. It can indicate a person/animal/thing doing an action. It can refer as well to an instrument or an inhabitant of a specific place. Recently I came across the verb *müllen* which means *Müll produzieren oder Müll wegwerfen*. Adding the suffix -er gives *Müller* which should expectedly relate directly to *müllen*. However *Müller* has a totally different unrelated meaning *miller*.

Is this one of a few cases in German where a very productive and **expected** suffix results in a noun with a totally different meaning? If this is frequent in German, can you give me other similar examples?

Comment: They are related. **Müll** historically is the screenings of by-product from a mill. It's good for nothing, not even for feeding animals. It's *Müll*.

Comment: And by the way, never heard of plain *müllen*, while *vermüllen* and *zumüllen* are widespread.

Comment: @Janka They are related historically. *Müll* and *Mühle* have even the same latin root. My question is about the **expected** current usage.

Comment: I never use *müllen*, but I frequently use *vermüllen*, *Vermüller*, *zumüllen*, *Zumüller*.

Comment: As a native speaker of german I don't use müllen in the meaning Müll produzieren oder Müll wegwerfen. The action of a Müller is mahlen, not müllen. Other examples: kochen-Koch but not Kocher. bauen does not fit to Bauer.

Comment: @Uwe But there is also "Kocher", as in "Wasserkocher", "Reiskocher", etc.

Comment: But Kocher is an appliance, but Koch is a person.

Comment: @Uwe *Kocher* is extremely expected. It's even one of the well-known usages *instrument* which I already mentioned in my question.

Comment: The Koch is the person standing in the kitchen preparing a hot meal. The Koch may use a Wasserkocher if a guest ordered a black tea. Der Müller mahlt Mehl in der Mühle. Der Koch kocht ein Mittagessen in der Küche. Der Spieler spielt in der Spielhölle. Der Sprecher spricht die Nachrichten im Studio. Der Bauer baut Getreide auf dem Feld an. Der Schiffbauer baut Schiffe.

Comment: A pun from childtime: *Wer guckt ist, ein Gucker. Wer spuckt, ist ein Spucker. Wer zuckt, ist ein Zucker? Wer geigt ist ein Geiger. Wer schweigt ist ein Schweiger. Wer zeigt ist ein Zeiger?*

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach This is a nice one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Müll* as a general term for "trash" or "garbage" is actually a relatively new word in the German language. It only shows up in this meaning around the 18th century. Before that time it was mainly used as a specific term only for waste that is produced when milling grain (this meaning seems to have died out today). The verb *müllen* is for producing trash is even newer and considered colloquial by most dictionaries.

In Austrian and Swiss German this word isn't even present (They are calling *Müll* *Mist* (A) or *Kehricht* (CH) ).

The substantiation "Müller" could thus simply not evolve for someone producing trash because it was already taken for the guy who mills the grain.

Not every productive suffix produces words with meanings you would expect:  A *Zitronenfalter*, as another example, is **not** a person that *folds lemons*, but rather a yellow butterfly, a *Bettvorleger* is **not** someone's dream job, and a *Gabelstapler* does not stack forks.

Comment: That is indeed a good explanation for this apparentely distinction in meaning in today language; However, my main concern is about the frequency of this phenomenon apart from its historical backgrounds?

Comment: Can you think of other similar examples or maybe this is the only case?

Comment: Added another one, and there are many more. Sometimes language defies logic.

Comment: Thank you; Recently I have been countering every now and then exceptions that contradict known language rules. So, I was thinking how far I should blindly trust these *known* rules. I have nothing against these very useful and helpful rules, but I would like it more if I have already been told about the presence of exceptions if there is any. Exceptions after all are an essential part of any rule in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

So you're trying to explore the limits, User? ;-) *Du willst wissen, wo die Grenzen sind?* Could we call you a *Grenzenwissenwoller* therefore? Yes, we, the native speakers, could, as a joke expressing mild disapproval.

Not joking, the following examples.

> Man kann eine Wand oder eine Tür streichen. Deshalb ist man aber kein
>   Streicher, denn ein Streicher ist derjenige, der in einem Orchester
>   ein Streichinstrument spielt. Wer berufsmäßig / hauptberuflich eine
>   Wand oder eine Tür streicht, ist Maler bzw. Lackierer.
>
> ---
>
> Man kann den Rasen sprengen. Deshalb ist man aber kein *Sprenger. Das
>   Wort existiert nicht eigenständig. Es kommt jedoch vor in
>   Rasensprenger (*lawn sprinkler*).
>
> ---
>
> Man kann die Blumen gießen, im Garten. Deshalb ist man aber kein
>   Gießer, denn ein Gießer ist derjenige, der in einer Gießerei (*foundry*)
>   arbeitet.
>
> ---
>
> Wer tatsächlich in die Zukunft sehen kann, kann also etwas
>   prophezeien. Dennoch ist er dann kein *Prophezeier, sondern ein
>   Prophet.
>
> ---
>
> Wer Übles ahnt, kann ebenfalls etwas prophezeien. Auch er ist kein
>   *Prophezeier, sondern eine Unke (not *a toad*, but from *unken* = to prophesy doom and destruction)
>
> ---
>
> Man kann an einer Krankheit leiden, deshalb ist man aber kein *Leider.
>   Entweder ist man der/die Kranke oder der/die Leidende.
>
> ---
>
> Man kann jemanden anstarren. Dennoch ist man dann kein *Anstarrer.
>
> ---

You see what it comes down to, *worauf es hinausläuft*. And yet, the quintessence of what I wrote is not a *Hinausläufer. :-))

Modal verbs are exemped from -er-transformations; except *können*.

*dürfen, mögen, müssen, sollen, wollen* do **not** have nouns like *der Dürfer, *der Möger, *der Müsser etc.  *können* does have a noun: *der Könner*. For detailed meanings, translations and usage, see https://www.dict.cc/?s=der+K%C3%B6nner

Jokingly, however, we could use these non-existing nouns derived from modal verbs.

If someone boasts with what he or she is allowed to do, *was er oder sie so alles darf*, we could say: *Na, du Dürfer, dann mach mal!* This would express disapproval of the boasting.

If someone laments about what he or she has to do / must do / is obliged to do, *was er oder sie so alles [tun] muss*, we could say: *Ach, du armer Müsser, du hast's wirklich schwer!* This would express disapproval of the lamenting.

The same, the joking, would be true for that *Blumen gießen*. If someone waters the flowers day and night, we could say: *Na, du alter Blumengießer, kommst du auch mal wieder rein? (= ins Haus)*. This would express mild taunting.

What does all this tell you? Try to tame your phantasy. Don't try to invent words. If you can't contain yourself, check whether your inventions can be found in / on www.dwds.de, www.duden.de, or www.dict.cc

Cheers!

Comment: You've made my day! Although you've indirectly or directly *rebuked* me several times before but honestly I ***loved*** it because it was helpful and funny :) This forum needs a little emotion and you provide it. The best part is when others might have unjustified reservations (IMHO) not to answer some questions and you came out of blue with the funniest helpful answer. Although not all your examples matched my idea but your answer was priceless and extremely helpful. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Es gibt einen Streicher aber auch einen Anstreicher, der Streicher spielt das Streichinstrument, aber der Anstreicher spielt nicht das Streichinstrument an sondern er streicht Wände an.

Comment: Man kann ein Glas Wein einschenken, aber wenn man das beruflich macht ist man nicht Einschenker sondern Kellner oder Schankkellner.

Answer (score 1):

Zur Wortbildung mit dem Derivationsmorphem *-er* und hier konkret zur Bildung von *nominibus agentibus* (Subjekten zur vom Verb bezeichneten Handlung) können auch Beispiele aus der Belletristik angeführt werden. Dies ist natürlich insbesondere dort interessant, wo ungewöhnliche, unübliche oder einfach nur neue Handlungssubjekt-Nomen geschaffen werden.

Sehr bekannt in dieser Hinsicht ist der ***Weinreinbringer*** aus Robert Gernhardts Gedicht "Deutung eines allegorischen Gemäldes", der in der letzten Zeile des Gedichts überraschend auftritt:

> Fünf Männer seh ich inhaltsschwer;
> wer sind die fünf?
> wofür steht wer?
>
> Des ersten Wams strahlt blutigrot;
> das ist der Tod
> das ist der Tod.
>
> Der zweite hält die Geißel fest;
> das ist die Pest
> das ist die Pest.
>
> Der dritte sitzt in grauem Kleid;
> das ist das Leid
> das ist das Leid.
>
> Des vierten Schild trieft giftignaß;
> das ist der Haß
> das ist der Haß.
>
> Der fünfte bringt stumm Wein herein;
> das wird der Weinreinbringer sein.

Man beachte jedoch, dass der *Weinreinbringer* hier bewusst zur Erreichung eines komischen Effekts eingesetzt wurde. Die Komik entsteht durch die Fallhöhe zwischen Allegorienverwendung in der Malerei der späten Neuzeit und dem Verzicht auf die Allegorienbildung im letzten Beispiel, das das Standardrepertoire allegorischer Figuren in der Kunst sprengt, oder jedenfalls das Standardrepertoire der Bekanntheit solcher Figuren bei Trägern des üblichen (bürgerlichen) Bildungskanons. Der bürgerliche Kulturkonsument wird hier in flagranti beim Strecken seiner Waffen erwischt; er mischt sich endlich unter das *normale* Volk, das einfach Männer mit rotem Wams, einer Geißel, einem grauen Kleid, einem grünen Schild und einer Karaffe Wein sieht und nicht weiter nach übertragenen Bedeutungen fragt.